# Await Promise.all async does't work in my code

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, promise

I have a lambda function with the structure below,
It used to work in older versions of nodejs but it doesn't work with the newer versions.
I know my code structure is quite messy and wrong but I can't get my head around it. I'm trying to use `Promise.all` but I'm obviously doing something wrong cause it's not getting executed at all.

By the way, I'm not getting any errors. The promise.all method never gets executed.

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    let result = {};

    try {

        result = await getOrder(sql, 0);

        result.map(
            (dataField) => {


            });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        callback(error);
    }

    var today_result = [];
    const groupKey = i => i.user_id + '_' + i.when;
    const counts = _.countBy(followingsIDs, groupKey);
    const isMulti = i => counts[groupKey(i)] > 1;
    const multiPropkey = i => ({ multiplekey: isMulti(i) ? groupKey(i) : groupKey(i) });
    const multiProp = i => ({ multiple: isMulti(i) ? counts[groupKey(i)] : 1 });
    const updated = _.map(followingsIDs, i => _.extend(i, multiProp(i), multiPropkey(i)));


    const uniqResult = _.uniq(updated, function(d) { return d.multiplekey });


    // Doesn’t execute from here —>
    await Promise.all(uniqResult.map(async(dataField) => {

        console.log("test_");

        dosomething()

        if (true) {

            let sql = `INSERT INTO ….`
            result = await getOrder(sql, 0);

            try {
                const data = await sns.publish(params).promise();

            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
                response.result = 'Error';
            }

        }

    }));

    // Till here <----

    callback(null, uniqResult);


};

let getOrder = async(sql, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            connection.query(sql, params, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                //      console.log("-----Query Done!");
                connection.release();
                //          console.log("-----Data: ", results);
                resolve(results);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: At least please structure/format your code before asking out for help. 
Also please try attaching the error logs as well which you get.

Comment: Sure, I try to fix the format. I don't get any errors. The Promise sections get ignored completely.

Comment: @AayushMall why do you have to flag down my question? you didn't wait for me to fix the format

Comment: Because the function passed to `uniqResult.map` doesn't return a promise?

Comment: @adimona also, you should ideally be formatting the question and providing all logs, details etc before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

What are you awaiting to? The `uniqResult` is just declared as an empty array. Immediately after that you pass it to Promise.all. You need to fill it with Promises and then pass it to Promise.all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just edited the code up here and added what goes into the ```uniqResult```. Could you please give me a hint on how to fill that constant with promises?

Comment: Why are you using it? I do not know what you are trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: The ```uniqResult``` returns modified objects that were fetched previously from the user table and were stored inside ```followingsIDs```.  Now that we’ve got the objects, in that the promise..all sections, I was going to scan the objects one by one and send notifications to each user if the time is right for them and then insert data into each user’s field and check them off so we know who got the notifications.

Comment: Then you may create another promise sendNotification and call it for each user in uniqResult. These promises should be added in another array lets call it notificationsArr like notificationArr.push(sendNotification()). After for loop finishes, you call Promise.all(notificationArr).